# Optgroup JSON + JS

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, json

Estou tentando agrupar o resultado de um json em 2 optgroups.

Segue o JS:

```js
//AJAX CARREGA LOJAS
$(function(){
 $('#estado').change(function(){
   if( $(this).val() ) {
     //$('#lojas').hide();
     $('.carregando').show();
     $.getJSON('inc/lojas.ajax.php?search=',{cod_estados: $(this).val(), ajax: 'true'}, function(j)
     {
       var options = '<option value="">ESCOLHA UMA LOJA...</option>';
       options += '<optgroup label="Franquias">';
       for (var i = 0; i < j.length; i++) {
         options += '<option value="' + j[i].franquias.id_loja + '">' + j[i].franquias.cidade + ' - ' + j[i].franquias.nome_loja + '</option>';
       }
       options += '</optgroup>';
       options += '<optgroup label="Multimarcas">';
       for (var i = 0; i < j.length; i++) {
         options += '<option value="' + j[i].multimarcas.id_loja + '">' + j[i].multimarcas.cidade + ' - ' + j[i].multimarcas.nome_loja + '</option>';
       }
       options += '</optgroup>';
     $('#loja').html(options).show();
     $('.carregando').hide();
   });

   }

 });
});
```

SEGUE O JSON:

```js
{
"franquias": [
{
"id_loja": "147",
"nome_loja": "JARDIM PAULISTA",
"cidade": "ATIBAIA",
"tipo": "Franquia"
}
],
"multimarcas": [
{
"id_loja": "114",
"nome_loja": "LOJA TESTE",
"cidade": "BARUERI",
"tipo": "Multimarca"
}
]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Um pouco diferente na notação, mas segue.

```js
jsonData = {
   "franquias": [
      {
              "id_loja": "147",
              "nome_loja": "JARDIM PAULISTA",
              "cidade": "ATIBAIA",
              "tipo": "Franquia"
      }
      ],
      "multimarcas": [
            {
              "id_loja": "114",
              "nome_loja": "LOJA TESTE",
              "cidade": "BARUERI",
              "tipo": "Multimarca"
            }
   ]
 };

function generateOptions(o_key, o_value) {
 let elements = [];
  elements.push('<optgroup label="' + o_key + '"/>');
  jQuery.each(o_value, function(i,o) {
   elements.push('<option value="' + o.id_loja + '">' + o.nome_loja + ' - ' + o.cidade + "</option>");
  });
  return elements;
}


var options = '<option>ESCOLHA UMA LOJA...</option>';
jQuery.each(jsonData, function(o_key, o_value) {
 options += generateOptions(o_key, o_value).join('\n');
});
$('#loja').html(options);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="loja">
</select>
```

Comment: Muito obrigado! É exatamente isso, só não estou conseguindo fazer com que busque o json online. Já tentei getJSON, json.parse, json.stringfy e nenhum funcionou :/

Comment: Mas pq? Dá algum erro no DevTools?